# How to get a fast Japanese car from 1979 or earlier?

Tags: gran-turismo-5

I'm a GT5 beginner and currently I'm at level 15 and want to finish the beginners series (a-spec) and need a good and fast Japanese classic car (<1979). But I can't buy one or I wasn't able to find it in the store. Does anyone know how to obtain such a car? I already bought a used Honda S500 but it's maximum speed is much to low to win on the Suzuka circuit.

Comment: @Dr. No: I made it to become third on the Suzaka circuit with the S500. But thanks for the answer, I'm going to give it a try.

Comment: @Dr. No: So far no luck with the "used cars dealership". Are there any other options to get a better Japanese oldie?

Answer (score 1):

Using the http://gt5cars.net/cars website you can view and filter all cars available in gt5.

In this case, you can filter all previous 1979 japanese cars, ordering by Power / weight.

[http://gt5cars.net/cars?utf8=%E2%9C%93&search[make_equals]=&search[year_gte]=&search[year_lte]=1979&search[country_equals]=Japan&search[level_gte]=&search[level_lte]=&search[price_gte]=&search[price_lte]=&search[drivetrain_equals]=&search[race_modifiable_equals]=&search[horsepower_gte]=&search[horsepower_lte]=&search[mass_gte]=&search[mass_lte]=&search[premium_equals]=&search[availability_matches]=&search[_type_equals]=&commit=Search](http://gt5cars.net/cars?utf8=%E2%9C%93&search%5Bmake_equals%5D=&search%5Byear_gte%5D=&search%5Byear_lte%5D=1979&search%5Bcountry_equals%5D=Japan&search%5Blevel_gte%5D=&search%5Blevel_lte%5D=&search%5Bprice_gte%5D=&search%5Bprice_lte%5D=&search%5Bdrivetrain_equals%5D=&search%5Brace_modifiable_equals%5D=&search%5Bhorsepower_gte%5D=&search%5Bhorsepower_lte%5D=&search%5Bmass_gte%5D=&search%5Bmass_lte%5D=&search%5Bpremium_equals%5D=&search%5Bavailability_matches%5D=&search%5B_type_equals%5D=&commit=Search)

There is no cars in the "new cars store" with that criteria, but you can find in the "used cars dealership".

In that case, I recomend you to try other races (seasonal events, another series a-spec) and inspect the used cars dealership (It refreshes after every race).

Comment: Still no luck with the used cars dealership, but I got the [DOME Zero Concept](http://gt5cars.net/cars/178) car from '78 after I finished the "Classic Super Cars" series. I think now I have the right car to finish the beginner series.